# How to digitize 90 degree angles?

Tags: qgis, plugins, digitizing, angles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create polygons with straight lines and right angles in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14150/how-to-create-polygons-with-straight-lines-and-right-angles-in-qgis)

In QGIS 1.8 is there a way to digitize buildings etc. with perfect 90-degree angles, Or, edit a polygon afterwards so that it has square sides?  I have a buildings shapefile.   I haven't been successful using the CAD Tools plugin.  Thanks to everyone with advice.