# How to create a polygon with specified dimensions?

Tags: qgis

I'm editing a shapefile in QGIS and want to draw in a rectangle with specified dimensions(Say 101ft by 305ft for example).

Is there a way in QGIS to make draw a rectangle with out actually have to use the mouse to manually place each of the points on the map?

What i'm really looking for is ArcMap type functionality where the users places the first point on the map with the mouse and then the user specifies the direction and length of each point relative to the first on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is similar to:

[How to create polygons with straight lines and right angles in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14150/how-to-create-polygons-with-straight-lines-and-right-angles-in-qgis)

I tried "azimuth and distance" plugin mentioned in second answer and after a while it is kind of easy to draw shapes (including squares) using azimuth and distance from first point - close to what you described in question :-)

Answer (score 1):

The closet thing I can think of would be the "Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds" plugin.  This is a little different to the ArcGIS functionality but you should be able to achieve a similar result.

This plugin effectively creates buffers from centroids but you can control the width, height and rotation of the rectangles, diamons and ovals which it is designed to produce with attribute fields.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but I have used the [CadInput](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/CadInput/) plugin to achieve this. It allows you to fix the x and y coordinates of your starting point. You can also define the angle.  From there you can draw your lines also defining the distance of each side of your polygon. Check it out. It helped me a lot.