# Draw rectangle in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3

I want to draw a perfect rectangle. How can I do that with QGIS v.3+?

[Here is a possible way to draw a rectangle in old QGIS versions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14150/how-to-create-polygons-with-straight-lines-and-right-angles-in-qgis).

Is there a similar solution for the latest QGIS version?

Comment: Please note that it is not helpful for the discoverability of good answers to duplicate questions every couple of years. You can [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw attention to the original question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).